# How to check whether file is readable - producing inexplicable error?

Tags: php

I've written the following segment of code to check whether an image file can be opened:

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM product 
          WHERE brand_id = '".$id."'
          ORDER BY active DESC, 
          product_id DESC";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 



    $filePath = 'http://www.example.com/130/'.$rows['product_id'].'.jpg';

    $handle = fopen($filePath,"r");
    if($handle){ ?>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/130/<?=$rows['product_id']?>.jpg"
    alt="" width="130" height="130" border="0" onerror="this.src='http://www.example.com/220/no_image.jpg'"/>
    <? } else { ?>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/220/no_image.jpg" alt="" width="130" height="130" border="0" />   
    <? } } ?>
```

This doesn't seem to be producing the correct result.

If when the file doesn't exist and therefore cannot be opened at the URL specified, it returns a miscellaneous image.

For example when testing this with `product_id` = 12997, the browser automatically redirects to `http://www.example.com/130/1997.jpg`.

So in theory the code is working, however, how do I prevent the browser from choosing the closest match `product_id` when the ID in question does not exist.

When trying to access the file at `http://example.com/130/12997.jpg` using `fopen()` the browser should produce a 404/403 error rather than arbitrarily redirecting to a similar exisiting `product_id` i.e. 1997.

Any advice would be great.

**UPDATE**

I found the full server file path for the images folder, and now `is_readable` is evaluating to true. However, when I use the same path within the `image src` tag a broken image is shown.

Any idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_readable` should work for you. It check if the file exists and is readable:

```
<?php if (is_readable($filePath)) { ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $filePath; ?>" alt="" width="130" height="130" border="0" />
<?php } else { ?>
   <img src="http://www.example.com/220/no_image.jpg" alt="" width="130" height="130" border="0" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is still returning as false? Any idea why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function `is_readable($filename)` (where $filename is the of the file to check) will return TRUE if the file is readable, false if not.

For example:

```
<?php if (is_readable($filePath) == TRUE) { ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $filePath; ?>" alt="" width="130" height="130" border="0" />
<?php } else { ?>
   <img src="http://www.example.com/220/no_image.jpg" alt="" width="130" height="130" border="0" />
<?php } ?>
```

Note that the $filename variable must be the path on the server, not the public http path, so you will to edit your $filePath variable so it points to the location on the server instead of the public URL.

Comment: The file is readable in the case given above, however, the function is still evaluating to false. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Apache may not be able to access the file. You need to check permissions (to make sure the web server can write to the file), or change ownership of the file to the webserver. You can do this via an FTP/SFTP client.

Comment: could this be because I'm giving the HTTP path to the file rather than the real file path?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the path to the file on the server, not via http.

Comment: Please see my update above - can you provide any advice?